# How Do I Validate a JSON file With a Schema in VB.Net?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, jsonschema

I'm trying to validate some JSON files on VB.net.
However, Whenever I run my code it gets stuck on

`Dim Schema As JsonSchema = JsonSchema.Parse(SchemaString)`

The Error Says

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll.

There is also a warning that says that JSON validation moved to its own package. So, I'm pretty sure I'm just importing the wrong packages, but I'm not sure.

I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the correct direction,

Thank you.

Here is my VB.net code

```
Imports System
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Schema
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Function Validate_JSON()

    Dim SplunkPath As String = "Z:\Database Project\Splunk Folder\Dropbox\Splunk_File.json"
    Dim SchemaPath As String = "Z:\Database Project\Schema Folder\Schema_File.json"
    Dim Schema_String As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(SchemaPath)
    Dim Schema As JsonSchema = JsonSchema.Parse(Schema_String)
    Dim Data_String As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(SplunkPath)
    Dim Data_JSON As JObject = JObject.Parse(Data_String)

    Dim Splunk_Status As Boolean = Data_JSON.IsValid(Schema)

    Return 0

End Function
```

Here is Splunk_File.json

```
{
  "Site": "USI",
  "SN": "21165",
  "MN": "F2C00W",
  "DateTime": "05/18/2021"
}
```

Here is Schema_File.json

```
{
    "$schema" :"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "properties": {
    "$schema": "#",
    "Site": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "SN": {
      "Type": "string"
    },
    "MN": {
      "Type": "string"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: We need a [mcve] to help you, specifically the contents of `SchemaString` and one specific `JSON_String` that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have made the changes to my question. Feel Free to ask more questions about my code.

Comment: Try removing trailing comma from "MN" block.

Comment: I made the correction but the same error occurred when I parse() my schema string.

Comment: The warning is because JamesNK moved the schema implementation into is own library. What's in the main JSON library is older code for backward compatibility, but it should still support draft 4 (as you're using).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$schema` is only valid at the root, and `properties` values MUST be schemas.

You have a `"$schema" : "#"` inside `properties`.  This means that you're trying to say that your JSON object should have a property called schema that can validate against the schema `#`.  But `#` isn't a valid schema object, so the parse fails.

You need to remove the `$schema` from your `properties`.

---

I'd also suggest using a later draft of the schema spec (if you have control over the schema).  Draft 6 is the oldest version that's compatible with the latest, 2020-12.

But for this you'll likely need to use a different validation package.  There are several available.  Mine is [JsonSchema.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net/).